# Unity. Замедление и ускорение времени в игре

Tags: android, ios, unity3d, разработка-игр

Не могу разобраться как сделать замедление и ускорение игры при подборе, например, какого то буста. Есть люди которые разбираются в Unity и могут с этим помочь? Просто не могу понять механику генерации таких бустов.

Comment: Туториал на YouTube по этой теме (ENG):
Slow-motion: [Тык!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VGosgaoTsw&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR6Wxj8HaJ_pZhBtaamtXL7J&index=14 "Тык")

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. Если я правильно понял вопрос, то [Time.timeScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Использование [Time.timeScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html), как указано выше, один из вариантов. Однако, это ускорит вообще всю игру и все процессы в ней. Например, таймер тоже пойдёт быстрее, если он у вас есть, и враги начнут бегать быстрее.

В играх часто используют какой-то общий модификатор. Например, условно, вы можете завести глобальную переменную, которая хранит текущий множитель скорости. Когда персонаж подбирает буст - этот множитель увеличивается и запускается корутина, которая через время сбрасывает множитель назад. А этот множитель можно использовать где угодно, например умножать скорость движения персонажа.

Можно завести два таких множителя и если игрок делает что-то не так или подбирает дебаф - ускорять всех врагов.
Можно завести такой множитель у самого персонажа и при подборе им буста - увеличивать множитель. Тогда можно будет реализовать подбор и ускорение в том числе и для врага.
В общем, вариантов реализации много, главное понять суть.